# Google Chart Range Filter Control not working inside Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, google-visualization

I made a simple HTML file and added it to my assets folder within my Android Studio. The file works perfectly when viewed directly on a browser. However, when viewed from inside of a webview or in a mobile device or emulator, the Google chart range controls are not draggable at all. The chart looks fine, but the controls are frozen. I can't find any help on this subject, so I would appreciate if someone could give me some pointers.

I have enabled Javascript on the webview and the jsapi.js is local inside of the assets folder too. Again, the chart looks fine. It's just the range control that is not working. Any ideas? The HTML code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='jsapi.js'></script>
<!--TO TEST LOCALLY IN A BROWSER, USE THE LINE BELOW-->
<!--script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script-->    
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {packages: ['controls']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(makeChart);
function makeChart( )
{
   var maxWidth = 400;
   var maxHeight = 400;
   var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
   data.addColumn('number', 'Stock');
   data.addColumn('number', 'Profit');
    for(var x=10;x<50;x++){
        data.addRow([x, x+1]);
    }
   var rangeFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
   controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
   containerId: 'range_filter_div',
   options:{
            filterColumnIndex: 0,
            ui: {
                chartOptions:{
                width: maxWidth,
                height: 50,
                chartArea: { width: '75%' }
                },
            minRangeSize: 1
        }
   },
   view: { columns: [0, 1] }
   }); 
   var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
   chartType: 'LineChart',
   containerId: 'chart_div',
   options: {
       width: maxWidth,
       height: maxHeight,
       chartArea: { width: '75%' },
       vAxis:{title:'Left Label'},
       hAxis:{title:'Bottom Label'},
       legend: 'none'
       }
   });
   var dash = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'));
   dash.bind([rangeFilter], [chart]);
   dash.draw(data);
} 
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<div id='dashboard'>
<div id='chart_div'></div>
<div id='range_filter_div'></div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

To enable Javascript on the WebView, here is the onCreate code for the main activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);

    //JavaScript is disabled on webviews by default
    WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();
    ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for starters, recommend using the newer library `loader.js`

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

instead of `jsapi`, according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic loader from now on.

this will only change the `load` statement, see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: makeChart,
  packages: ['controls']
});

function makeChart( )
{
  var maxWidth = 400;
  var maxHeight = 400;
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'Stock');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Profit');
  for(var x=10;x<50;x++){
      data.addRow([x, x+1]);
  }
  var rangeFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
    containerId: 'range_filter_div',
    options:{
      filterColumnIndex: 0,
      ui: {
        chartOptions:{
          width: maxWidth,
          height: 50,
          chartArea: { width: '75%' }
        },
        minRangeSize: 1
      }
    },
    view: { columns: [0, 1] }
  });
  var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'LineChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div',
    options: {
      width: maxWidth,
      height: maxHeight,
      chartArea: { width: '75%' },
      vAxis:{title:'Left Label'},
      hAxis:{title:'Bottom Label'},
      legend: 'none'
    }
  });
  var dash = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'));
  dash.bind([rangeFilter], [chart]);
  dash.draw(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<div id="range_filter_div"></div>
<div id="dashboard"></div>
```

Comment: doubt this will help, primarily added the snippet so i could test on my phone -- but the _Run code snippet_ button isn't available there...

Comment: Thanks WhiteHat, to run this code as an app you have to add the HTML file above and the loader.js include to the assets folder of an empty Android project, then add a simple WebView to a blank activity. Give Javascript permissions to the WebView and then load the HTML file. I will update the jsapi.js file to loader.js and see if this works tonight...

Comment: I just tried it with the new loader.js code and it works just as good. But, the range control still doesn't work at all inside of webview, unfortunately.

Comment: you mentioned to run as an app, you must _add loader.js to the assets folder_ -- you're downloading the file locally, it's not possible to run from the normal url? -- i know the `'controls'` package performs requests back to their server, will it have access to do so?

Comment: I just tried it using the https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js CDN instead of the reference to the local assets folder. The chart still works, so it is not necessary to use the assets folder, but unfortunately, the controls remain frozen.

Answer (score 0):

Even ChartRangeFilter in example https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#chartrangefilter_1 does not work on android browser. So code or library may not have anything to do with its non functionality, it simply may not be supported by android yet.